# PHPMailer - Gmail settings - Error 10060

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

Apologies for adding to the collection of PHPMailer / Gmail question. I've read them all, and still can't get this to work. First the error message:

> 2015-03-25 16:22:44 Connection: opening 
> 2015-03-25 16:22:54 SMTP
>   ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond. (10060) SMTP connect() failed. Message was not
>   sent. Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed.

This code is the same that I have used many times to successfully send emails from a `secureserver.net` account, so I'm pretty confident that the script is solid. The problem must be in the gmail settings that I am trying to use(?).

```
try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // Using SMTP.
        $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Enables SMTP debug information - SHOULD NOT be active on production servers!
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = 'true'; // Enables SMTP authentication.
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server host.
        $mail->Port = 587; // Setting the SMTP port for the GMAIL server.
        $mail->Username = "XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username (GMail email address).
        $mail->Password = "XXXXXXXXXX"; // SMTP account password.
        $mail->AddReplyTo('XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'me'); // Use this to avoid emails being classified as spam - SHOULD match the GMail email!
        $mail->AddAddress('someone.else@gmail.com', 'Someone Else'); // Recipient email / name.
        $mail->SetFrom('XXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'me'); // Sender - SHOULD match the GMail email.
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication';
        $mail->Body = 'Test Body';
        $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
        // $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
```

I've also tried port 465/ssl (and even 25, although this almost certainly won't work). I have verified with telnet that I can reach port 587:

> telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 
> Trying 2607:f8b0:4001:c11::6c... 
> Connected
>   to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com. 
> Escape character is '^]'. 
> 220
>   mx.google.com ESMTP f1sm1137441igt.14 - gsmtp

What am I missing? I've been over this for hours, and I don't see anything wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;` (as real boolean value)?

Comment: I did. Many times. Same result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471693/phpmailer-using-gmail-gives-error/42472146?noredirect=1#comment72085437_42472146

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)?

Use `SMTPDebug = 4` for debugging low-level connection (as opposed to SMTP) problems.

Are you sure you're using latest PHPMailer? Your code looks like it's from an old example.

It would be good to eliminate PHPMailer from the test, as I suspect your problem is lower level. Write a simple script that just does an `fsockopen` to port 587 and reads from it, like this:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen('tcp://smtp.gmail.com', 587, $errno, $errstr, 10);
echo fgets($fp, 128);
fclose($fp);
```

If that works, you will see something like `220 mx.google.com ESMTP eo1sm5152802wib.16 - gsmtp` from that.

If that doesn't work, suspect things like php.ini settings, disabled functions, missing extensions etc.

Comment: Good suggestions. Thanks very much. The `fsockopen` command is throwing a 500 error, so it looks like I need to figure that out. Funny how it works fine with the other email address, though. I haven't updated my PHPMailer code for about a year, so it might be out of date. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, did you solve your problem? I currently have the same issue. :)