# Why can't I connect to the gmail SMTP server using tls?

Tags: php, networking, network-programming, phpmailer

My target is to send an email to myself using PHPMailer. I am using Gmail SMTP as a start (I have enabled less secure app access and disabled two factor authentication), and am trying to connect from localhost (using MAMP). This is my code:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
$mail = new PHPmailer(true);
try {
  $mail->SetFrom('myemail','myname');
  $mail->AddAddress('myemail','mynickname');
  $mail->Body = 'There is a great disturbance in the Force.';
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
  $mail->Port = 587;
  $mail->Send();
}
catch (Exception $e){
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

This gives me a SMTP connect() failed error. I checked the troubleshooting page for this and have found that this error occurs when there is a Firewall or DNS failure, so I have tried disabling the firewall on my computer altogether, but to no avail. What could be the problem?

It is worth noting that I have tried connecting to the smtp server on cmd using `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` and that didn't work either. What could be the problem here?

Edit: I changed `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` and `$mail->Port = 587;` to `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'`; and `$mail->Port = 587;` respectively it worked. Why does tls not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPMailer - Gmail settings - Error 10060](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261374/phpmailer-gmail-settings-error-10060)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
```

In the `try{` section to help narrow down the errors